# Ningún resultado con "mongoose.connection.db.collection" buscando por "_id" (ObjectId)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando buscar un documento por "_id" en una colección cuyo nombre viene dada dinámicamente con el siguiente código, ya que el nombre de la colección es dinámico.

```
let collection = req.params.collection;
mongoose.connection.db.collection(collection, function(err, collection){
    collection.find({ **_id: "5c47611939115b35f0c7b247"** }).toArray(function(err, data){
       return res.status(200).json({ message: "File upload successfully", data });
    });
});
```

El _id está generado con ObjectId... he probado de mil maneras pero no consigo que me saque ningún documento a pesar de estar correcto el _id...

He probado con `{ _id: "ObjectId('5c47611939115b35f0c7b247')" }` etc... en fin, de mil maneras...

Lo curioso es que si la query la cambio por `{ title: "title-ejemplo" }` sí que me saca los documentos cuyo título sea "title-ejemplo", es decir, solamente me pasa cuando consulto por _id... ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Prueba así: `collection.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("5c47611939115b35f0c7b247")}).toArray`

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta.
Así como dices me da el siguiente error en consola:
 
"Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided."

Comment: Puede que estés seteando mal la vista o enviando mal la salida, no lo sé realmente. Si quieres [revisa esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23595282/5587982) y sus respuestas.

Comment: Mongoose tiene su propia función **findById(_id)**. Prueba con eso en vez de solo find y le mandas el id únicamente

Comment: Hola. Gracias por tu respuesta.
La cuestión es que necesito pasarle el nombre de la colección dinámicamente... (atención: el nombre de la colección, no el nombre del Modelo ni el Schema). 
No he encontrado cómo hacer esto con Mongoose, así que encontré una solución que lo hacía de esta manera... pero al hacer el find por _id es cuando casca...

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Y solamente me da error si hago el find sobre el _id?
Si lo hago con cualquier otra propiedad funciona correctamente, pero necesito que sea con el _id

Comment: ¿Tú estás usando Node.js? Otra forma en la que puedes probar es: **`collection.find(ObjectId("5c47611939115b35f0c7b247")).toArray`**

Comment: De esta manera sigue fallando...
Otra solución que se me ocurre es poder hacer un find directamente con mongoose -- algo parecido a **NewsCategory.findbyId("5c47611939115b35f0c7b247")** --
pero no encuentro manera de sacar el nombre de un modelo de manera dinámica ( ya que me vendría por parámetro "newsCategories", el nombre de la colección)

Comment: puedes agregar la definicion de tu coleccion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que no usas el tipo de variable correcta. Has intentado, como dices, usar varias opciones y ninguna ha funcionado. @A.Cedano te dio una pista al decirte que debes usar `ObejectID`, sin embargo lógicamente te arrojó un error, ya que no has instanciado el método `ObjectId`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se requiere realizar una consulta a MongoDB usando el ODM Mongoose, el nombre de la colección a la que haremos la consulta viene dado de forma dinámica como parámetro de la URI, de la forma: `/api/:collection`. El `id` mediante el que realizaremos la consulta es fijo y viene dado en forma de cadena de texto `id: "5c47611939115b35f0c7b247"`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la consulta a la base de datos, usaremos el método `ObjectId` de Mongoose, de la clase `Types`. El método lo instanciamos de la siguiente manera:
`const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;`.

La forma en que vas a implementar entonces tu búsqueda podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
//(ES6)
import mongoose from 'mongoose'; // importante tener importado mongoose
//(ES5)
//var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId; // instanciamos el método ObjectId


app.route('/api/:collection')  // asumimos que ya express está configurado
    .post((req, res, next) => {

        let collectionName = req.params.collection; // instanciamos el nombre de la colección
        let id = ObjectId('5c47611939115b35f0c7b247'); // aqui creamos el objeto id
        mongoose.connection.db.collection(collectionName, (err, collection) => {
            if(err) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'Error al procesar los datos.'
                });
            } // fin err
            collection.find({_id: id}).toArray((err, data) => {
                if(err) {
                    res.status(400).json({
                        error: 'Error al realizar la consulta.'
                    });
                } // fin err
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: data
                });
            }); //fin collection.find.toArray()
        }); // fin mongoose.connection.db.collection()
    }); // fin app.route.post()
```

De esta manera podremos realizar la consulta a la BD usando el objeto `id` apropiado.

Espero que te ayude a resolver el problema.

Puedes consultar la documentación de:

[Mongoose.prototype.Types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-Types)

[Direccionamiento de Express](http://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html#app-route)

Comment: Eso es! Solamente me faltaba instanciar ObjectId...

con **const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;** bastaría...

Muchas gracias!!