# MongoDB Express NodeJS Relacionar correctamente dos Schemas

Tags: json, nodejs, express, router

Buenas tengo estos **Schemas** :

**Temporadas.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var db = require('../libs/db-connection')();
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    const temporadasSchema = new Schema({
        numero:Number,
        url_imagen:String,
        fecha_emision:String
    });

    return db.model("temporadas",temporadasSchema);
}
```

**Capitulos.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var db = require('../libs/db-connection')();
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    const capitulosSchema = new Schema({
        numero:Number,
        titulo:String,
        resumen:String,
        temporada: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "temporadas"}
    });

    return db.model("capitulos",capitulosSchema);
}
```

Estoy intentando relacionarlo de la siguiente manera:

**1 temporada tiene N capitulos**

Los **Schemas** los plantee de la manera que puse, ahora bien, la consulta estoy intentando algo como esto:

**He hardcodeado el id temporada para no complicarme demasiado al principio** esta consulta me da un array vacio.

Lo que pretendo es : **Dame todos los capitulos de la temporada con id 5ca24ba649704f9cdd72bcd4**

```
Temporada.find({_id:"5ca24ba649704f9cdd72bcd4"},function(err,capitulos){

 Capitulos.populate(capitulos, {path: "temporadas"}, function(err,capitulos){


      res.status(200).send(capitulos);

      }

)})
```

Ya se que MongoDB son bases de datos nosql, por tanto **no relacionales** simplemente quiero conseguir simular la **relacion**

Comment: Hola, podrías leer [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249344/relaciones-entre-collections-mongo/249626#249626) respuesta donde doy una explicación de relaciones en MongoDB. Tal vez te sea de utilidad. Otra cosa que te puedo decir es que si vas a pasar el valor `_id` hardcodeado en tu consulta desde Express, debes convertirlo primero en `ObjectId`, tal como sugiero en [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233741/ningún-resultado-con-mongoose-connection-db-collection-buscando-por-id-obj/234146#234146) respuesta. Saludos

Comment: La primera respuesta que te sugerí en mi comentario anterior aplica a MongoShell, es solo para que tengas claro el concepto de **Base de Datos noSQL**. Para relacionar esquemas en Mongoose puedes ver [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250826/error-relacionando-modelos-con-mongoose/250876#250876) otra respuesta.

Comment: Aún no comprendo porqué realizas la conexión a la base de datos en el esquema. Por otro lado, el método `populate()` lo usas incorrectamente.